# How to create widgets in one notebook by calling from another notebook

Tags: python, azure-databricks

How to create the widgets in databricks notebook1 by specifying the widgets in Notebook2.
I have a requirement like I'm specifying all the code and dbutils widgets in Notebook2.
when I call Notebook2 from Notebook1 , all commands are executing while widgets are not getting created in Notebook1. How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and if you are getting any error.

Comment: @PratikLad when i keep all widgets details and run it from another notebook, it isn't creating any widgets

Comment: can you please share screenshots of what you are exactly trying to do and error you are getting?